# Finding the set containing maximum empty rectangles for all the points in space

Tags: geometry

Given a 2D space limited by a (white) rectangle and a set of (black) rectangles occupying that space I am looking for a way to somehow index the empty (white) space. For that purpose I would like to create a set of (white) rectangles such that for any given point in the space (point not belonging to any "black" rectangle) maximal empty rectangle exists in that resulting set of white rectangles. I would like the solution in the function of rectangles and not the pixels.

Thanks

Edit:

To be more precise, I need to list all the maximal empty rectangles (rectangles populated with only white points, which cannot be extended in any direction without including a black point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-53487-3_50](http://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-53487-3_50)
This paper describes an efficient approach to my problem.

Regards,
Damjan

Comment: Can you please share algorithm for above problem . I am unable to access above paper.

Comment: It is difficult to cover all of the details. Unfortunately I cannot access the paper currently as well.
The basic idea is to sort all of the points by Y coordinate first and start a "curtain" from the top. When the curtain hits an edge, it "stops" that curtain it currently had and places it in the list of rectangles, and then starts one or two new curtains (two if the edge was in the center of the previous curtain), but two new curtains start from the same Y as the previous curtain, only their X and width change. You can optimize the edge finding with a segment tree.